# Looking for a best way to read images from MongoDB

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot

I'll provide a [link of website](https://tripadvisor-app-demo.herokuapp.com/) so you can understand better what I'm trying to achieve.

If you go on link and then go on > `Adventure Holidays` > `Summer Camps` you will get on page where site provide you a random document from collection. So far there is just two documents but you'll get it. So, I want to have different image from each documents that user get.

If user get `Kieve Summer Camp` show him image of Kieve Camp and so on. But I'm stuck.

Is a better option to create Photo collection and then that collection to connect with every other collection and than compare IDs from photo collection with other documents from other collection? Or is a better way to add field photo on each document and get that image like I'm now getting title, description and etc?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your needs. The sentence with collection 5 times in it is very confusing. I thing your question is if you should embed or reference the images. In my opinion it would be the beste to store images file based an store just a Link in MongoDB. MongoDB is not a file storage and limited to 16MB per document. I don’t know how big your images are but a file based storage would be the best solution.

So if you stick to your solution I would say to store each image as an own document, maybe with metadata, in a Collection just for images.

Comment: Okay, so acutally it would be better If I upload images somewhere and then in my document add field for that image link and then read that link and show image?

Comment: Exactly. This is how I would recommend it.

Comment: But if I want to solve this on that way, what If I want to create feature that will allow user to save document with image? He will also insert the link to the image for image field? Instead of choosing it locally

Comment: I mean, if I have CREATE operation, user besides other filed as title, descirption will have field for URL instead of choosing image locally